# Why the parallelization of the following code takes too much to run?

Tags: r, time, foreach, parallel-processing

The following piece of code is supposed to be very easy to run. In sequential mode it is executed in less than a second. However when I make it parallel it seemingly takes forever to run. If I set the vector lengths to 100 the code runs fine so I don't think it's a structural issue.

```
  library(foreach)
    library(doParallel)
    cl <- makeCluster(4)
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    bvec <-as.vector(1:1e3)
    avec <-as.vector(1:1e3)
    sim= function(x,y) 10*x+y
    system.time(x <-
       foreach(b=bvec, .combine='cbind') %:%
       foreach(a=avec, .combine='c') %dopar% {
         sim(a, b)
         })
```

What is the catch? 
Appreciated.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Imagine you don't have a computer and you need a computation done. You send 3 friends letters asking them to do pieces of the computation, they do them and send you the results back and you put it all together. If each piece of computation takes a long time to do, this is efficient even though you have to wait on the mail. However, if each piece of computation is very simple it would be faster to just do yourself.

Comment: For example, if each piece of computation takes 1 month to do, it would take you 4 months by yourself, but even waiting 4 days for the mail it's 1 month + 4 days with your friends - much more efficient. However, if each piece of computation takes 1 hour, you could do it in 4 hours yourself or 4 days + 1 hour with your friends. Waiting on the mail just slows you down.

Comment: And to wrap it up you and your friends are processors, the mail is the overhead of working in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. I get the point. So basically I should expect to see the improvement only when the task at hand is overly complex?

Comment: Right. You want each piece of the task (each iteration or whatever) to take substantially more time than it takes to send the task to the individual processor and compile the result.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism requires quite a bit of overhead. Since your 'sim' function is computationally cheap, the cost of the overhead overwhelms the performance benefits from executing 'sim' in parallel. That's why you get the expected results with larger vector lengths.